# call a method of object from another class

Tags: java, oop

I have three classes, the first class makes a box on screen and there is a method to screen capture the contents of the box. In the second class several boxes are instantiated and in the third class there is a jframe with a button. When the button is pressed I want to call the captureComponent method but just for one  specific box which has been created. I am new to Java and I have been really struggling to see how I can achieve this. I have been staring at this code for several days. I think that it will be something simple. All the individual classes work fine and ideally the class arrangement should stay as it is.

I have created the following code to demonstrate the issue I am having. It is a simplified representation of my actual code, as otherwise it would be too big to put on SO. The line I am having trouble with is Box.a.captureComponent(); in the Button class.  What is the correct way to call the method of one particular object from a different class?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Box {

    public Box() {
        // Code to displays a transparent box on screen with a border
    }

    public void captureComponent()  {
       // This method screen captures whats displayed in the box
    }
}



public class Object_Instantiate {

      // In this class two boxes are created a & b              

        Box a = new Box();
        Box b  = new Box();     

}


public class Button {

    /*In this class there is a button. When I press it I want to call 
    the captureComponent method but just for box a*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Code to create JFrame with button would go here

        btnSnap.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();
                if (clickedButton == btnSnap) {

                    //CaptureComponent method of just Box a    
                    Box.a.captureComponent();

                }                
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Box` doesn't have any static `a` of type `Box`, so you can't use `Box.a.captureComponent();`.

you need to create an instance of `Box` then call `captureComponent()`, since it is a instance method.

ex :

```
Box b  =new Box();
b.captureComponent();
```

Comment: Thanks, not quite what I wanted but managed to find a solution. Have a happy new year.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all you need only one main function, that's the point where your program starts. Then you can create objects with `Box BoxName = new Box();` in the main. After that you can handle the object with `BoxName.captureComponent();`

Maybe it's helpful to read some stuff about classes.